# Woocommerce reduce inventory programmatically when related variation is purchased

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, stock, product-variations

Ok, will do my best to explain the problem.
I am selling limited edition prints on my site. They come in multiple sizes, and they also come framed and unframed.

Right now, I set up each product to have 2 attributes: size & frame.
Within the variations, I have 4 options

- 11x17 unframed
- 11x17 framed
- 20x30 unframed
- 20x30 framed

The problem occurs with the inventory. There are 10 total 11x17 prints, but since I have to enter a stock quantity for each variation, I have to do something like this:

- 11x17 unframed 10qty
- 11x17 framed 10qty

Which makes it seems as though there are 20 total prints, instead of 10.

Ideally, I'd want to keep inventory based on attribute, not variation, but there doesn't seem to be a way to do that.

I am unable to set up the Frame as an add-on product because the cost of the frame goes up, as the size of the print goes up.

I am wondering, if there is a way to programmatically reduce the stock of other variations, when one variation is purchased. So, when someone purchases the "11x17 unframed", the "11x17 framed" stock is reduced -1 at the same time.

All of the products on the site are exactly the same, so I wouldn't mind hard-coding the specific variation names in the code.

Not sure if something like this is doable, but I would hugely appreciate any insights.

This is the closest example I could find to customizing how stock is handled:
[Reduce WooCommerce Item Inventory By Attribute Value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49680378/reduce-woocommerce-item-inventory-by-attribute-value)

Thanks in advance,
Jenny

Comment: If you are open to plugins I think this one: https://woocommerce.com/products/product-add-ons/ would fit the bill.

Comment: I think it is important to include in your question the fact that you need to charge different prices for framed / not-framed. If it were not for this you could use the existing functionality of WooCommerce. The issue you have is due to the fact that WooCommerce assumes that quantity and price are managed at teh exact same level.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. The price of framed & unframed are different. And the price of the frame itself goes up with the size of the print. So, a frame for an 11x17 costs less then a frame for a 20x30, making it impossible to set up as an add-on product.