# Reduce and check stock of Variable Product by Attribute Value

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Using [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49681282/7690982) to reduce the stock from inventory by Attribute Value. It works to reduce the stock, but when you have like 100 g in stock and the customer buys 120 g. It doesn't show Out of Stock.

So the following code was created:

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');

    // The 'pa_size' attribute value is "15 grams" And we keep only the numbers
    $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);

    // Calculated new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_grams ) && $quantity_grams != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_grams;

    if($quantity > $stock_quantity) {
        return $quantity;
    } else {
        echo '<p>Out of Stock</p>';
    } 

}
```

However, it isn't working...

Is there a way to check the stock from $quantity?

```
    if($quantity > $stock_quantity) {
        return $quantity;
    } else {
        echo '<p>Out of Stock</p>';
    }
```

**EDIT:**

Tried to reduce the stock with a hook to `wc_reduce_stock_levels`, without success

```
add_filter( 'wc_reduce_stock_levels', 'filter_reduce_stock_levels', 5, 1); 
function filter_reduce_stock_levels( $order_id ) { 
    if ( is_a( $order_id, 'WC_Order' ) ) { 
        $order = $order_id; 
        $order_id = $order->get_id(); 
    } else { 
        $order = wc_get_order( $order_id ); 
    } 
    if ( 'yes' === get_option( 'woocommerce_manage_stock' ) && $order && apply_filters( 'woocommerce_can_reduce_order_stock', true, $order ) && sizeof( $order->get_items() ) > 0 ) { 
        foreach ( $order->get_items() as $item ) { 
            if ( $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) && ( $product = $item->get_product() ) && $product->managing_stock() ) { 
                $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');
                $qty = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', $item->get_quantity(), $order, $item ); 
                $item_name = $product->get_formatted_name(); 
                $new_stock = wc_update_product_stock( $product, $qty, 'decrease' ); 
                $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);
                $qty *= $quantity_grams;
                if ( ! is_wp_error( $new_stock ) ) { 
                    /** translators: 1: item name 2: old stock quantity 3: new stock quantity */ 
                    $order->add_order_note( sprintf( __( '%1$s stock reduced from %2$s to %3$s.', 'woocommerce' ), $item_name, $new_stock + $qty, $new_stock ) ); 

                    // Get the latest product data. 
                    $product = wc_get_product( $product->get_id() ); 

                    if ( '' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_no_stock_amount' ) && $new_stock <= get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_no_stock_amount' ) ) { 
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', $product ); 
                    } elseif ( '' !== get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_low_stock_amount' ) && $new_stock <= get_option( 'woocommerce_notify_low_stock_amount' ) ) { 
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_low_stock', $product ); 
                    } 

                    if ( $new_stock < 0 ) { 
                        do_action( 'woocommerce_product_on_backorder', array( 'product' => $product, 'order_id' => $order_id, 'quantity' => $qty ) ); 
                    } 
                } 
            } 
        } 

        // ensure stock is marked as "reduced" in case payment complete or other stock actions are called 
        $order->get_data_store()->set_stock_reduced( $order_id, true ); 

        do_action( 'woocommerce_reduce_order_stock', $order ); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: Try to echo $quantity and $stock_quantity to see which one of them is not assign ?

Comment: It is not echoing anything, dunno if I am right. Because i am a PHP noob. However, nothing is printed on the page... With `echo $stock_quantity;`
    `echo $quantity;`

Comment: You can achieve this with [Attribute Stock for WooCommerce](https://wordpress.org/plugins/attribute-stock-for-woocommerce/) if you don't want to muck about with code snippets.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove all your old codes and add these to your theme's 'functions.php'.

```
// reduce stock based on 'pa_weight' attribute
add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');

    // 'pa_weight' attribute value is "15 grams" - keep only the numbers
    $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);

    // new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_grams ) && $quantity_grams != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_grams;

    return $quantity;
}

// check out of stock using 'pa_weight' attribute
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation', 'woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight' );
function woocommerce_validate_attribute_weight() 
{
    // get product id
    if (isset($_REQUEST["add-to-cart"])) {
        $productid = (int)$_REQUEST["add-to-cart"];
    } else {
        $productid = null;
    }

    // get quantity
    if (isset($_REQUEST["quantity"])) {
        $quantity = (int)$_REQUEST["quantity"];
    } else {
        $quantity = 1;
    }

    // get weight of selected attribute
    if (isset($_REQUEST["attribute_pa_weight"])) {
        $weight = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $_REQUEST["attribute_pa_weight"]);
    } else {
        $weight = null;
    }

    // comparing stock
    if($productid && $weight)
    {
        $product = wc_get_product($productid);
        $productstock = (int)$product->get_stock_quantity();

        if(($weight * $quantity) > $productstock)
        {
            wc_add_notice( sprintf( 'You cannot add that amount of "%1$s" to the cart because there is not enough stock (%2$s remaining).', $product->get_title(), $productstock ), 'error' );
            return;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

The first function almost same as your's and you cannot show out of stock message using the `woocommerce_order_item_quantity` since it will execute only after successful order confirmation.

You need to validate the new stock while adding your product to the cart which can be achieved by using the second function (utilizing `woocommerce_add_to_cart_validation`).

Comment: Are you using latest WooCommerce version? Can you able to share your store URL?

Comment: PHP code just gets echoing on top of your page? View the source code in your browser.

Comment: Yes I know, but why the raw code shown over there? Probably you may added without `<?php` tag?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180998/discussion-between-outsource-wordpress-and-danieltakeshi).

Answer (score 0):

I never used woo commerce but I see that you are trying to get number from e.g. `15 grams`. I am not sure but most probably you should do same thing for `$stock_quantity` as well. The final code should be something like this. And I also noticed that you are checking that if requested quantity is grater than stock quantity then return it which is not logical. It should be vice versus. I mean requested quantity should be less or equal to stock quantity.

```
<?php

add_filter( 'woocommerce_order_item_quantity', 'filter_order_item_quantity', 10, 3 ); 
function filter_order_item_quantity( $quantity, $order, $item )  
{
    $product   = $item->get_product();
    $stock_quantity = $product->get_stock_quantity();
    $term_name = $product->get_attribute('pa_weight');

    // The 'pa_size' attribute value is "15 grams" And we keep only the numbers
    $quantity_grams = preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $term_name);
    $stock_quantity = (int)preg_replace('/[^0-9.]+/', '', $stock_quantity);

    // Calculated new quantity
    if( is_numeric ( $quantity_grams ) && $quantity_grams != 0 )
        $quantity *= $quantity_grams;

    if($quantity <= $stock_quantity) {
        return $quantity;
    } else {
        return '<p>Out of Stock</p>';
    } 
}
```

Comment: It didn't work. I think the function to check the stock quantity is wrong or when the product is bought, it is not calling out of stock correctly. I tried other functions but without success

Comment: Also tried to `do_action( 'woocommerce_no_stock', $product );` instead of echo Out of Stock

Comment: I changed code. Can your try again. Most probably when you call `filter_order_item_quantity` method the caller expects that you will return something but you print something instead. That's why I changed echo with return.

Comment: Reading about the [hooks from wc](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/introduction-to-hooks-actions-and-filters/), the add_filter is used to change some functions of Woocommerce, so I think that `filter_order_item_quantity` can't reduce stock. So I will have to use another function. So i tried to used `wc_reduce_stock_levels` instead, but without success

Comment: Did you use my code? Because I changed it a couple of minutes ago.